# Error Google Maps getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Google Maps me muestra el siguiente error:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

**¿Qué puedo hacer para que funcione en una url http?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta corta: No, no puedes.

Pero hoy en dia puedes hacer certificados gratuitos SSL. por lo que no hay excusas para no usarlos.

[letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) te permite firmar, renovar y todo automatico certificados SSL, es super facil y rapido de usar.

te dejo una guia en ingles [aqui](https://lucaschmid.net/anotherblog/letsencrypt-express).

edit:

agrego la referencia al [error](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only).